# Alert dialog issue when used with Api response

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow

I am new to Jetpack compose and trying to show an alert dialog when my API call response is error, So I am using FLOW for the data updates. When observing the response object in my composable function, in the Error condition I am setting this value to "true" and displaying the dialog. But I am not able to dismiss it. I am sure it's not the right way to do it as the showDialog gets recomposed and sets the value to "true" always.

```
var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

```
is NetworkResult.Error -> {

            errorMessage = (loginResponse as NetworkResult.Error).message!!
            showDialog = true

            if (showDialog){

                AlertDialog(message = errorMessage, onDismiss = { showDialog = false }) {

                    showDialog = false
                }
            }
```

Can someone guide me to a proper way of handling this?

I tried using the LaunchedEffect, but I got the below.

```
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
```

Comment: If you can write all the code of this class I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Each time composable recompose. It goes back to the `Error State` of response where you set `showDialog = true` which causes the dialog to reopen again and again.

One solution is when code reaches some state in `NetworkResult` then set the `networkState = null`. So, when composable recompose. It will not execute the `NetworkResult.Error` code.

The code can look like this

```
  if(networkState == null){
     return
  }
  when(networkState){
      is NetworkResult.Error -> {
         // error state
      }
      is NetworkResult.Success -> {
        // success state
      }
  }
  networkState = null
```

`networkState` should be declared in `ViewModel`. So, `networkState` will not change or reset due to recomposition.